# React re-render restarting video

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a react app with some complex view logic. There is one view where I need to have different parents and conditional renders. This causes my stream ref to be lost, or a video to restart. Is there anyway to set this up so my video instance can reach the new view state without restarting?

I've tried display none but it messes with my view, visibility hidden restarts the video.

here's a sandbox of my problem.

https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-wood-qnn2x0?file=/src/App.js:0-1004

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution I thought of.

```js
import { useState } from "react";
import React from "react";

import "./styles.css";

let flex = {
  display: "flex"
};
let leftParent = {};

let VidInstance = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  return (
    <div style={{ display: !props.mute ? "flex" : "none", width: 200 }}>
      <video
        controls=""
        preload="none"
        autoPlay
        src="https://archive.org/download/BigBuckBunny_124/Content/big_buck_bunny_720p_surround.mp4"
        width="200"
        muted={props.mute}
      ></video>
    </div>
  );
});

export default function App() {
  let [view, setView] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <flex style={flex}>
        <leftParent style={leftParent}>
          <Box />
          <Box />
          <VidInstance key="vid" mute={view} />
        </leftParent>
        <VidInstance key="vid" mute={!view} />
      </flex>
      <button onClick={() => setView(!view)}>view</button>
    </div>
  );
}

let Box = () => {
  let boxStyle = {
    width: "200px",
    margin: "2px",
    height: "100px",
    background: "blue"
  };
  return <div style={boxStyle}></div>;
};
```

1. Loading both `VidInstance` at same time to sync their play time.
2. Wrap `VidInstance` with a wrapper `div` and give that `div` same width as the video to reserve the empty space when your video goes hidden.
3. Pass `mute` prop to `VidInstance` to mute and hide inactive video.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the tag `<source>` inside the video tag... its worked for me:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```